# Google is not indexing my website

Tags: seo, google-search-console

So I submitted my sitemap to google search console which includes 3.5k URLs. At first, it said pending so that's alright.

Now it says it indexed 1 page and when I resubmit it again it doesn't show pending. No errors in the search console.

I even validated my sitemap and robots.txt files and they are both ok. Any idea why this is happening? thanks